# How to split a String at all special characters except dot?

Tags: java, regex, split, special-characters

```
String line="word,1.2;3.1!4.5";
```

What regex should I use in `Split(...)` to remove all special characters except dot? (I need the dot to keep double and float values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?!\\.)\\W
```

You can also use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cD5jK1/4

Answer (score 4):

You may try this,

```
string.split("[^.\\w]");
```

or

```
string.split("[^.a-zA-Z\\d]");
```

Add `+` after the character class, if you want to apply split on one or more  characters.

Comment: a general question, don't you need to escape . (`dot`) ?

Comment: no, dot looses is special meaning inside the char class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
line.split("[.\w]");
```

Comment: Thank you for answers, "[^.a-zA-Z\\d]" or "[^.\\w]" , works well, but `String line = "\\//word,1.2;3.1!4.5?!!!!^^*%$^$^$";`

but for `String[] lineSplited = line.split(pattern);` where `String pattern="[^.a-zA-Z\\d]"` or `String pattern="[^.\\w]"` , i have this output : 

`lineSplited :  
lineSplited :  
lineSplited :  
lineSplited :  word
lineSplited :  1.2
lineSplited :  3.1
lineSplited :  4.5`

Please how to deal with \\ or // ?

thank you again